# "Chrome detected unusual code" error in previously working iframe

Tags: php, google-chrome, xss, web-development-server

I had a perfectly working PHP page with an iframe inside. Suddenly it stoped working in Chrome with this error:

> Chrome detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information...

Any idea how to solve  it?

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes, the question is vague on porpoise because it is not dependent on the page code but on a change on Chrome. Please explain so I can improve it if you think something is missing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking around found that Chrome changed its default implementation of X-XSS-Protection to 'X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block' ([reference](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=654794))

So the fastest solution (and involving the least change in code) is to disable X-XSS-Protection by sending a value of 0 from the server.

Here is how to do it from PHP

```
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome changed its default implementation of X-XSS-Protection to 'X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block' and mainly this issue found in Chrome Version 60 and window 10 PC see the below reference link related t this issue

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702542

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706038

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4MUJd75N4Jw

Comment: Looks like a patch was committed for this in Chromium bug 702542, but who knows how long that'll take to reach mainstream Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The other posts here offer an ***answer***.  But none of them offer any code-sample-based ***explanation***, so, I will try :

This is caused by a webpage displaying HTML that was `POST`'d to it, when that HTML contains JS event triggers, for example :

```
<p class="someParagraph" onClick="doTheMagicThing();">
```

If you have an iframe, that receives text like this in a `POST` or a forum, and you display that text, as well, then Chrome will issue the error (and effectively block the page), unless you have the `X-XSS-Protection` header disabled.

Naturally, passing huge swathes of html like this between independent components is not considered good design.